# Mandrill create activation code in template

Tags: javascript, php, html, mandrill

I have question concerning Mandrill. I have set up a template. In that template I want to add an activation code for my users. However, Mandrill does not allow the use of javascript and php in the template. Does any one know how I could an activation code dynamically in Mandrill's template?

Thanks

Comment: if it helped you, will you accept my answer please :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with your use case but Mandrill offers merge tags for dynamic content in the form of `*|FNAME|*`, `*|LNAME|*` etc...

You can create your own tags following instructions/guide on the Mandrill [knowledge base](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21678522-How-do-I-use-merge-tags-to-add-dynamic-content-).

You can then create html links in the following manner

```
<a href="http://example.com/activate?uid=*|ACTIVATEID|*">Activate your whatever</a>
```